# AS2- Input Text to lead to a different frame?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, macromedia

There's a button I have in which the player should be able to enter a code. If they put in the correct code, they're taken to the "correct" frame, but if they're wrong, they should be taken to the "wrong" frame. The problem I'm encountering is that regardless of the text inputted, the player is taken to the "wrong" screen. Here's my current code:

```
on (release) {
if (combo eq "blue"){
gotoAndStop("correct");
} else {
gotoAndStop("wrong");
}
}
```

and i've also tried the if() statement being

```
if (combo == "blue")
```

The input textbox has a variable name of 'combo' and an instance name of 'code'.

Comment: Did you test `trace(combo)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the [`eq`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000658.html) operator was deprecated since Flash Player 5 in favor of the [`==`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000631.html)(equality) operator.

On the other hand, to get the selected `item label` of your combo box, you have to use it's [`value`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002016.html) property:

> Read-only property; if the combo box is editable, value returns the
>   item label. If the combo box is static, value returns the item data.

**Your code:**

```
on (release) {
    if (_parent.combo.value == "blue") {
        gotoAndStop("correct");
    } else {
        gotoAndStop("wrong");
    }
}
```

Other remark : It seems that *combo* should rather be written *_parent.combo*